# How add multiple fields to select statement in JOOQ?

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I'm trying to add fields to select after the first initialization. It seems that there is no way to do it as it just recreates one.

```
String select = "actor_id,first_name,last_name,last_update";
DSLContext context = DSL.using(SQLDialect.DEFAULT);
Select select = context.select();
for (String field : select.split(",")) {
    select = context.select(field(name(field)));
}
System.out.println(select.getSQL());
// The value is always SELECT last_update ... 
// But I need select actor_id,first_name,last_name,last_update ...
```

I don't see a way to keep the select and then add WHERE, LIMIT etc as subsequent steps as and when required in the code flow. Should everything be done in the same step?

Something like:

```
select = select("test");
// code
// code
select = select("another field");
// code
// And add other sql statements to the DSL and finally get the sQL
```

Answer (score 1):

in the snippet you've provided, the value of `select` is always "last_update" because the for-loop re-assigns `select` on each iteration. the last evaluated value is "last_update", so naturally, that's what `select` ends up being.

here's an approach that initializes the `Select` with the full range of columns to select, rather than building it up field-by-field:

```
final List<Field<?>> projection = new ArrayList<Field<?>>();

final String columnNames = "actor_id,first_name,last_name,last_update";

for(String columnName : columnNames.split(",")) {
    projection.add(field(name("Tblactor", columnName)));
}

Select query = context.select(projection);
...
```

hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

While [hsl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45261477/521799) shows a much better approach of storing the entire projection in a local variable, I'll just briefly comment on the mistake you made, which is simple:

```
SelectSelectStep select = context.select();
for (String field : select.split(",")) {

    // Your code: This always creates a new select statement from scratch
    // select = context.select(field(name(field)));

    // The code you meant to write
    select = select.select(field(name(field)));
}
```